# What do these weird errors logged mean?

Tags: postgresql, statistics, logging

Today, I got these errors logged for the first time:

```
stats_timestamp 2022-01-16 10:58:25.625142+01 is later than collector's time 2022-01-16 10:58:23.356175+01 for database 0
statistics collector's time 2022-01-16 10:58:25.625142+01 is later than backend local time 2022-01-16 10:58:23.355776+01
```

It worries me. What causes it to happen? What does it mean? I found nothing whatsoever online.

Windows 10 Pro 2009. PostgreSQL 14.1.

Comment: any differences in SELECT CURRENT_TIME; and your windows date?

Comment: @AmineC I thought that PG (like all software) used the system time?

Comment: That's why i'm intrigued to know, i'll take that as a no

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [ntpd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ntpd) (or whatever Windows calls its version of that) set your system clock back a few seconds to get you back in sync with the atomic standards.  The stats collector noticed that time briefly moved backwards and complained.

It unlikely to be worth bothering with, but maybe you could set it up to sync more often, so each change is smaller